# Conditional Event Handlers in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a scenario where I want to add Mouse and Keyboard Events for Drag and Drop Data on DockPanel/TextBlock based on few conditions in Data Model. If that condition doesn't exist, then I don't want my code to listen for those events.

```
<!-- Data Template with all event handlers -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:EventsViewModel}">   
    <DockPanel Name="dpnMain">
                <Button Name="btnSourceLink" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="0"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        Click="Button_OnMouseButtonUp"
                        PreviewMouseDown="Button_DragDataMouseDown"
                        Content="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource RegionalDataFormatConverter}}"
                        ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}"
                        ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding IsTooltipAvailable}" />
                <StackPanel Name="spnWithDragNDrop" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" ClipToBounds="True" Padding="0"
                               Text="{Binding Label}" MouseEnter="OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave" 
                               MouseLeftButtonUp="OnMouseLeftButtonUp"
                               PreviewMouseDown="DragDataMouseDown"
                               ToolTip="{Binding Label}"
                               Width="{Binding ElementName=spn, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay,
                                Converter={StaticResource WidthFromParent}, ConverterParameter=10}"/>
                </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
<DataTemplate>


<!-- Data Template without event handlers -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:PlainViewModel}">    
    <DockPanel Name="dpnMain">
                <Button Name="btnSourceLink" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="0"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        Click="Button_OnMouseButtonUp"
                        PreviewMouseDown="Button_DragDataMouseDown"
                        Content="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource RegionalDataFormatConverter}}"
                        ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}"
                        ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding IsTooltipAvailable}" />
                <StackPanel Name="spnWithoutDragNDrop" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" ClipToBounds="True" Padding="0"
                               Text="{Binding Label}"
                               ToolTip="{Binding Label}"
                               Width="{Binding ElementName=spn, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay,
                                Converter={StaticResource WidthFromParent}, ConverterParameter=10}"/>
                </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
<DataTemplate>

<!-- Content Control will select the appropriate data template based on the view model it is bound to -->
<ContentControl Focusable="False" Padding="0" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

I don't want to write two different Data Template and want to select based on it's viewModel type. I need some kind of ValueConverters that would bind to these events.

Is there anyway I can write some converter to avoid writing another DataTemplates and View Model and converter would look into those conditions behind the scenes?

Comment: Could you detect the condition within the listener, and just ignore the event there instead?

Comment: can you use ICommand and attached behavior for your implementation?

Comment: @JonSkeet That's what I am doing it right now. But I was wondering if there is better solution than this.

Answer (score 0):

create a class with this code:

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    private static DataTemplate _eventsViewModel;
    private static DataTemplate EventsViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (_eventsViewModel== null)
                _eventsViewModel= Application.Current.FindResource("EventsViewModel") as DataTemplate;
            return _eventsViewModel;
        }
    }

    private static DataTemplate _plainViewModel;
    private static DataTemplate PlainViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (_plainViewModel== null)
                _plainViewModel= Application.Current.FindResource("PlainViewModel") as DataTemplate;
            return _plainViewModel;
        }
    }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if(item is EventsViewModel) return EventsViewModel;
        else if(item is PlainViewModel) return PlainViewModel;

    }
}
```

in xaml in resources tag:

```
<core:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="myTemplateSelector"/>
```

in xaml:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelector}"/>
```

Comment: I know I can do it through TemplateSelector or Content Binding. For example, we have BoolToVisibilityConverter as ValueConverter with each binding. I am looking for some ValueConverter, that would set binding rather than creating few different data templates to do almost similar things in two templates.

Comment: If you don't want to duplicate everything, you can replace the TextBlock with that ContentPresenter and write DataTemplates for different states of TextBlock.